# How to update the state when 1 option in tag select is clicked and navigte to another screen in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With this problem, I only can navigate to another screen, but I can't update the state of the tag select.

```
//Here is the code I handle to navigate when I click on 1 option.

const onChangeNav=(e)=>{ props.history.push (`/${e.target.value}`) }


//Here is my list of option

 <select className="select" onChange={onChangeNav}>
    <option value="Expression"> 
         Expression 
    </option>
    <option value="editing">
         Editing 
    </option>
    <option value="exceeded">
         When Exceeded 
    </option>
    <option value="tracking" >
         Tracking
    </option>
</select>
```

So I click 1 of them. For example, when I click **Editing**, I will be navigated to **Editing** screen then the in the select will show **"Editing"**.
Thank y'all !

Answer (score 0):

To show the current selected value, you need to maintain the value in the state.

```
const Dropdown = (props) => {
    const [selected,setSelected] = useState('');
    
   useEffect(()=> {
       if(selected) {
           // you can use a setTimeout here to delay the redirection
           props.history.push (`/${selected}`)
        }
   },[selected])

    function onChangeNav(){ 
        setSelected(e.target.value);
        
    }

    return (
        <select className="select" onChange={onChangeNav} selected={selected}>
            <option value="Expression">Expression</option>
            <option value="editing">Editing</option>
            <option value="exceeded">When Exceeded</option>
            <option value="tracking">Tracking</option>
        </select>
    );
}
```

This would ensure that you have a value selected in the dropdown before redirecting to a new page.

Comment: setting state is of no use, it will no longer available when redirected

Comment: so what exactly is the use case. Do you want to cause the redirection after the state has been updated ? please see the updated answer

Comment: when you are navigating ,the ID component will unmount. So the state would be destroyed. If you want to keep the state, then it should be maintained in Redux.